C# Mapster mapping error when using multiple objects
I'm trying to use the Mapster Tuple mapping to map from a 7 object to a single one. The objects are composed from classes that represents DTO's and models from my databse, but i'm getting an error that is a bit hard for me to identify the cause.
The destination class is the following:
using Api.Domain.Model.Base;

namespace Api.Domain.Model
{
    public class Demand : BaseTable
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
        public virtual string Department { get; set; }
        public virtual string Benefits { get; set; }
        public virtual string Details { get; set; }
        public virtual string Restrictions { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Responsible { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Match> Matches { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Keyword> Keywords { get; set; }
    }
}

The conversion code and their respective classes are:
The service class where the business logic is implemented
public async Task<CreateDemandResponse> Create(CreateDemand createDemand)
{
    var user = await userService.GetUserAsync();
    var status = await statusRepository.SelectAsync();
    var person = await personRepository.GetAsync(createDemand.Responsible.Email, createDemand.Responsible.Phone);
    var laboratories = await laboratoryRepository.SelectAsync();
    var keywords = await languageService.ExtractGpt(createDemand.Adapt<Description>());
    var analysis = await languageService.Analyze((createDemand, laboratories).Adapt<Analyze>());
    var demand = (user, person, createDemand, status, laboratories, keywords, analysis).Adapt<Demand>();

    await demandRepository.InsertAsync(demand);

    return (demand, laboratories, analysis).Adapt<CreateDemandResponse>();
}

The User class:
using Api.Domain.Model.Base;

namespace Api.Domain.Model
{
    public class User : BaseTable
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual string Password { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
        public virtual Laboratory Laboratory { get; set; }
    }
}

The Person class:
using Api.Domain.Model.Base;

namespace Api.Domain.Model
{
    public class Person : BaseTable
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Department { get; set; }
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
    }
}

The Laboratory class:
using Api.Domain.Model.Base;

namespace Api.Domain.Model
{
    public class Laboratory : BaseTable
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Code { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Responsible { get; set; }
        public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual string Certificates { get; set; }
        public virtual string FoundationDate { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Software> Softwares { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SocialMedia> SocialMedias { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Match> Matches { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Keyword> Keywords { get; set; }
    }
}


The Keyword class. Please note that i'm using a Collection of this class:
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Api.Contracts.Common
{
    public class Keyword
    {
        [JsonRequired]
        [JsonPropertyName("text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [JsonRequired]
        [JsonPropertyName("weight")]
        public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    }
}

The analysis class. Please note that i'm using a Collection of this class:
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Api.Contracts.LanguageApi.Response
{
    public class AnalyzeResponse
    {
        [JsonRequired]
        [JsonPropertyName("laboratory_id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonRequired]
        [JsonPropertyName("score")]
        public decimal Score { get; set; }
    }
}

And finally, my mapping configuration:
TypeAdapterConfig<(User user, Person person, CreateDemand demand, 
    ICollection<Status> status, ICollection<Laboratory> laboratories, 
    ICollection<Api.Contracts.Common.Keyword> keywords, 
    ICollection<AnalyzeResponse> analisys), Demand>
    .NewConfig()
    .Ignore(dest => dest.Id)
    .Map(dest => dest.Title, source => source.demand.Title)
    .Map(dest => dest.Description, source => source.demand.Description)
    .Map(dest => dest.Company, source => source.user.Company)
    .Map(dest => dest.Department, source => source.demand.Department)
    .Map(dest => dest.Benefits, source => source.demand.Benefits)
    .Map(dest => dest.Details, source => source.demand.Details)
    .Map(dest => dest.Restrictions, source => source.demand.Restrictions)
    .Map(dest => dest.Responsible, source => source.person ?? source.demand.Responsible.Adapt<Person>())
    .Map(dest => dest.Keywords, source => source.keywords
        .Select(x => new Keyword { Text = x.Text.ToLower(), Weight = x.Weight })
        .Concat(source.demand.Keywords.Select(x => new Keyword { Text = x.ToLower(), Weight = 1 }))
        .GroupBy(x => x.Text)
        .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(k => k.Weight).First())
        .ToList())
    .Map(dest => dest.Matches, source => source.analisys.Select(x => new Match
    {
        Score = x.Score,
        Laboratory = source.laboratories.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Id == x.Id),
        Status = source.status.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == (int)MatchStatus.Analysed)
    }).ToList());

The problem is a StackOverflow exception when calling the mapping. it generates a bunch of the follwing lines:
at DynamicClass.lambda_method555(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1<Api.Domain.Model.Software>)

followed by:
at DynamicClass.lambda_method554(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Api.Domain.Model.Match>)
   at DynamicClass.lambda_method485(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Object)
   at Mapster.TypeAdapter.Adapt[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Object, Mapster.TypeAdapterConfig)
   at Mapster.TypeAdapter.Adapt[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Object)
   at Api.Services.DemandService+<Create>d__7.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>, System.__Canon)
   at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation+<>c__DisplayClass14_0`2+<<BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0>d[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation+<>c_
_DisplayClass14_0`2+<<BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0>d[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Refit, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2f9b1262776509f5]].ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation+<>c_
_DisplayClass14_0`2+<<BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0>d[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Refit, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2f9b1262776509f5]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation+<>c_
_DisplayClass14_0`2+<<BuildCancellableTaskFuncForMethod>b__0>d[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], Refit, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2f9b1262776509f5]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>, System.__Canon)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0>d, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0>d, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0>d, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>, System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler+<<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler+<<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0>d, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler+<<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0>d, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler+<<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0>d, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>, System.__Canon)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler+<<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler+<<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0>d, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler+<<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0>d, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler+<<SendCoreAsync>g__Core|5_0>d, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>, System.__Canon)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler+<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler+<SendAsync>d__4, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler+<SendAsync>d__4, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler+<SendAsync>d__4, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>, System.__Canon)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler+<SendAsyncCore>d__10.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler+<SendAsyncCore>d__10, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler+<SendAsyncCore>d__10, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler+<SendAsyncCore>d__10, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>, System.__Canon)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync>d__89.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync>d__89, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync>d__89, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync>d__89, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachineBox, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].TrySetResult(System.__Canon)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.__Canon>, System.__Canon)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+<SendAsync>d__57.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+<SendAsync>d__57, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].ExecutionContextCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+<SendAsync>d__57, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+<SendAsync>d__57, System.Net.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].MoveNext()
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs+<>c.<.cctor>b__173_0(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool+IOCompletionPoller+Callback.Invoke(Event)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolTypedWorkItemQueue`2[[System.Threading.PortableThreadPool+IOCompletionPoller+Event, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Threading.PortableThreadPool+IOCompletionPoller+Callback, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool+WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()


I tryed removing the Matches from the mapping and do it mannualy after, but then i got a bunch o similar errors but with the messeage:
at DynamicClass.lambda_method491(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1<Api.Domain.Model.Demand>)


So, anyone with expirience with Mapster know wth is going on? If more information about the models involved is necessary just ask. Thanks for the help!
